# Is there a way to conditionally import multiple react imports?

Tags: reactjs, import

I am importing all of these below. It seems like a lot of lines. Is there a way to conditionally/dynamically import these somehow? Here there are 7 different data files, but there could be much more.

```
import React from "react";

import Mod1Data from "../data/Mod1Data";
import Mod2Data from "../data/Mod2Data";
import Mod3Data from "../data/Mod3Data";
import Mod4Data from "../data/Mod4Data";
import Mod5Data from "../data/Mod5Data";
import Mod6Data from "../data/Mod6Data";
import Mod7Data from "../data/Mod7Data";
```

I am setting passing them like this, but still lengthy.

```
  //lessons import
  const lessons = {
    Mod1Data,
    Mod2Data,
    Mod3Data,
    Mod4Data,
    Mod5Data,
    Mod6Data,
    Mod7Data,
  };

  //set lesson # to local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("lesson", JSON.stringify(lesson));
  }, [lesson]);

  const properties = {
    lesson: lesson,
    data: lessons["Mod" + lesson + "Data"],
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <Component {...properties} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: [Dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)?

Comment: I notice it says use dynamic import only when necessary. I wonder if this is the appropriate case I guess its preference. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Hard to say; the benefit is that you can construct the import names in a loop. As an answer states you could also export a single object from a file and manage the imports manually within that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the data folder you could create an index.js file where you export all the
data files.

Like so:

```
export Mod1Data from "../data/Mod1Data";
export Mod2Data from "../data/Mod2Data";
export Mod3Data from "../data/Mod3Data";
```

And then when you import you do:

```
import * from `path\to\index`
```

This will contain all your data inside a JS object. So it will be easier to import to different files.

Comment: Sorry do you mean put all the code from each data file into one index.js and then export them like above? The data files each contain quite a bit of code is why i ask) OR do you mean just add an index.js file to the data folder, and import and export in the same index file?

Comment: Okay so I did move all the imports to an index.js file then exported from there. I thought maybe it was best to keep the static imports in there. Thanks!